# Mirror Cell Excel with If Term

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell, mirror

I want to mirror e.g. cell B2 to C2 only when it say #T1 at the beginning. 
For example I'd like to mirror B2 to C2 when it says "#T1 Global" but not when it only says "Global".

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula in cell `C2`...

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,3)="#T1",B2,"")
```

And here is another formula to do the exact same thing...

```
=REPT(B2,LEFT(B2,3)="#T1")
```

Comment: It says that theres a problem with the formula.

Comment: Are you using a version of Excel than uses a semicolon instead of a comma to separate parameters? There's nothing wrong with the formula. It  works perfectly.

Comment: Ok, that's been part of the problem. But now it says #NAME? in C2 when #T1 stands in B2.

Comment: Could you post an image of your sheet with the cursor in cell C2? The two formulas above are working perfectly here.